# GROUP BY Show 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making a report to show the number of applicants that we get each week from a school. We recruit at 15 different schools. My current query is this. The problem being, if a school doesn't get an applicant then they won't show up in the report. How can I have the school appear even if no applicants?

```
SELECT 
weekofyear(tbl_job_applications.ja_date) AS 'Week #',
tbl_universities.univ_name,
Count(tbl_job_applications.ja_date) AS 'Applicants'
FROM
tbl_job_applications
    Inner JOIN
tbl_universities ON tbl_job_applications.univ_id = tbl_universities.univ_id
    Inner JOIN
tbl_positions ON tbl_job_applications.pos_id = tbl_positions.pos_id
where year(tbl_job_applications.ja_date) = 2014
Group by tbl_universities.univ_name , weekofyear(tbl_job_applications.ja_date)
Order by weekofyear(tbl_job_applications.ja_date) DESC , tbl_universities.univ_name ASC;
```

Comment: Change the inner joins to right join from applications to universities.  Inner will only show records if all tables have the value.  a right or left will show all values from the table on the left or right regardless if a match is found in the related table.

Comment: inner joins filter rows out, outer joins don't. so so start with positions as the the main table and then left join to applications and  to universities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN`.  `INNER JOIN` excludes non-joining values, also your `WHERE` criteria needs to be altered to not exclude records that have no `ja_date` value:

```
SELECT  weekofyear(a.ja_date) AS 'Week #'
      , u.univ_name
      , COUNT(a.ja_date) AS 'Applicants'
FROM    tbl_universities u
LEFT JOIN tbl_job_applications a
    ON a.univ_id = u.univ_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_positions p
    ON a.pos_id = p.pos_id
WHERE   YEAR(a.ja_date) = 2014  OR a.ja_date IS NULL
GROUP BY u.univ_name
      , weekofyear(a.ja_date)
ORDER BY weekofyear(a.ja_date) DESC
      , u.univ_name ASC;
```

Note, this will return all `univ_name` values, but it won't return every `univ_name` value for every week, if that's what you're after you need to create a driver that has all week and univ_name combinations, easiest to do this using `CROSS JOIN` in a subquery (in this example it's limited to only weeks with an applicant for at least 1 of the schools, if you wanted all weeks you'd have to set that up differently):

```
SELECT sub.*,COUNT(a.ja_date)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
             weekofyear(a.ja_date) AS week_
            ,u.univ_name
            ,u.univ_id      
      FROM tbl_job_applications a
      CROSS JOIN tbl_universities u
      ) as sub
LEFT JOIN tbl_job_applications a
    ON a.univ_id = sub.univ_id
    AND weekofyear(a.ja_date) = sub.week_
LEFT JOIN tbl_positions p
    ON a.pos_id = p.pos_id
GROUP BY sub.univ_name
        ,sub.week_
ORDER BY week_
         ,sub.univ_name
```

Demo of both: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8de9/15/0)

Comment: The logic makes sense. Not sure why but this does not yield the results I'm looking for. It gave me the same results as the Inner Join.

Comment: Can you provide sample data?

Comment: There are about 100 schools in the tbl_universities database. Of those, there 15 we actively recruiting. These are the ones I'd like to show  The tbl_job_applications looks like this - 
Application Date, Name, Email, Univ_ID 

Current export looks like this -- 
School, Week #, Count of Applicants, 
'Georgia','13','1'
'Illinois','13','1'
'Michigan','13','3'
'Ole Miss','13','1'
'Tennessee','13','1'

Comment: Let me know if there is anything else I can provide. I'm new to stackoverflow and mysql so not sure exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @user3465711 See updated answer.  It's both changing to outer joins and altering your `WHERE` criteria, since the `WHERE` criteria will exclude records with no `ja_date` since you only want records with a year of 2014.

Comment: Ah awesome. Second one is exactly what I was after. Thanks for the answer. Also, for the pointer on cleaning up the code with aliases. Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Alter query so universities are listed first and use an outer join:

```
FROM tbl_universities 
LEFT JOIN tbl_job_applications
  ON tbl_job_applications.univ_id = tbl_universities.univ_id
INNER JOIN tbl_positions 
 ON tbl_job_applications.pos_id = tbl_positions.pos_id
```